# Mercurial notification extension globs ignored

Tags: mercurial, mercurial-hook

I am attempting to use file patterns to limit push notifications to specific directories. The following glob patterns in [usersubs] are not triggering emails, though the basic patterns of asterix and double asterix work. OS: Windows XP.

```
**.sql
*.sql
one/*.sql
**.???
**/*.sql
```

repos contents are:

```
.hg
root.sql
/one/one.sql
```

hgrc is:

```
[extensions]
notify =

[hooks]
incoming.notify = python:hgext.notify.hook

[email]
from = me@company.com

[smtp]
host = 12.34.56.78

baseurl = 

[notify]
sources = serve push pull bundle
test = False
config = 

[usersubs]
me@company.com = **.sql

maxdiff = 300
```

Process used:
1) clone the repo with these settings
2) change the two sql files listed so they can be committed
3) hg commit -m "comment here"
4) hg push

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The notify extension doesn't support using patterns to match particular files.  From "hg help notify":

> [usersubs]
>      # key is subscriber email, value is a comma-separated list of repo patterns
>      user@host = pattern
>
> [reposubs]
>      # key is repo pattern, value is a comma-separated list of subscriber emails
>      pattern = user@host
>
> A "pattern" is a "glob" matching the absolute path to a repository, optionally
>      combined with a revset expression. A revset expression, if present, is
>      separated from the glob by a hash.

The patterns listed in the question are being treated as patterns to match the absolute path to a repository.

Possible alternatives:

- Split the files that you desire notification for into a separate repository (which should then be supported by the notify extension)
- In Mercurial 2.4, try using a revset reposubs pattern, such as "*#file('*.sql')=me@company.com".
- Write a custom hook to perform your desired notification based on detection of per-file changes
- Instead of using notifications, have the recipients watch for changes on per-file RSS feeds provided by hgweb (suggested by mpm on IRC)

Comment: I was able to get this to work using a revset pattern. For some reason globs didn't work so I used the following: *#file('re:.*\.sql'). The pattern that didn't work is *#file('*.sql') and that fails with the error "incoming.notify hook failed: *.sql not under root"